# Bounds on complex vector equations using the 2-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-equations

Let $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ be vectors of size $n {\times} 1$ and $m {\times} 1$, respectively, and let $\boldsymbol{A}$ be a matrix of size $m {\times} n$. Suppose $\boldsymbol{x}$, $\boldsymbol{y}$ and  $\boldsymbol{A}$ are over the complex field $\mathbb{C}$.

I have this simple vector equation:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}.
\end{equation}

I need to find a bound on $|| \boldsymbol{y} ||_2$ in the form of:
\begin{equation}
|| \boldsymbol{y} ||_2 \ge \alpha || \boldsymbol{x} ||_2,
\end{equation}
where $\alpha > 0$ is a constant and $||\:.||_2$ is the 2-norm.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Note: I did find a bound with the opposite inequality sign, specifically, 
$|| \boldsymbol{y} ||_2 \le ||\boldsymbol{A}|| \: || \boldsymbol{x} ||_2$, where $||\boldsymbol{A}||$:= $\sup_{||\boldsymbol{x}||_2 \le 1} \{||\boldsymbol{Ax}||_2\}$.

Comment: Choose $\alpha = 0$. If $A$ is singular, this is the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks. But while $\alpha$ = 0 would work, it generates a trivial bound on $||\boldsymbol{y}||$, i.e., $||\boldsymbol{y}|| \ge 0$. I edited the question to take care of this special case of $\alpha$.

Comment: I presume you meant $\alpha >0$. There is such a constant **iff** $A$ has a trivial kernel. Look at the SVD for a quick proof.

Comment: Yes, I was correcting that when you put the last comment :)

Comment: The best bound in general will be the smallest singular value of $A$.

Comment: Actually the matrix with trivial kernel is good for the statement I need to make. Could you please provide just a proof sketch or a good link to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\underline{\sigma} = \min_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \|Ax\|_2$.

Note that $\underline{\sigma} > 0$ **iff**  $\ker A = \{0\}$ (this follows from
compactness of the unit ball).

$\underline{\sigma}$ is the smallest singular value of $A$.

A standard reference (overkill in this instance) would be "Matrix Computations"
by Gene Golub, Charles Van Loan & Justin Bieber. I am not sure about the last author.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to be able to help.